# Lebesgue Integral of $\sin(x)/x$ using the Monotone convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

How can I show using the monotone convergence theorem that the Lebesgue integral $$\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}x\,dx$$ does not exist?

Comment: This may be a problem, because it's not absolutely integrable... Are you sure that you have an obligation to use the Lebesgue integral, etc?

Comment: Well then is it possible to use MCT to show that sin(x)/x is not lebesgue integrable?

Comment: The monotone convergence theorem applies best to non-negative functions, and _can_ prove that a sequence of integrals goes to $+\infty$. But the absolutely divergence of this integral does not imply non-convergence when signs are taken into account.

Comment: How would one use MCT to prove any integral does not exist?

Comment: Monotone convergence doesn't seem like the easiest approach/relevant. It is fairly straightforward by comparing $\int_{[0,\infty)}\frac{|\sin x|}{x}\,dx$ with appropriate harmonic series that the integral is $+\infty$, hence $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I guess depending on what we mean by "does not exist", the MCT can prove that an integral is $+\infty$... which, while having some meaning (in that context), can mean "does not exist", in another context. So MCT can prove that an integral blows up...

Comment: But it does exist, no?

Comment: I suppose the goal should be to show that $\int_0^{+\infty}\left | \frac {\sin x}x\right|dx$ is $+\infty$?

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $f$ is (Lebesgue) integrable if and only if $|f|$ is Lebesgue integrable. Now, we may write $$f_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{|\sin x |}{x}\chi_{[k \pi , (k+1)\pi]}$$ so that $f_{n} \leq f_{n+1}$ and $f_n \to f$ pointwise, where $f(x) = \frac{|\sin x |}{x}$. We may then estimate the integral of each term in the sum via:
$$\frac{2}{(k+1)\pi} = \int_{k \pi}^{(k+1)\pi} \frac{|\sin x|}{(k+1)\pi}dx \leq \int_{k \pi}^{(k+1)\pi} \frac{|\sin x|}{x}dx$$

So that by the monotone convergence theorem,
$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \frac{|\sin x|}{x}dx &= \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^\infty f_n dx \\
&\geq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2}{(k+1) \pi} \\
&= \infty
\end{align*}$$
Which implies that the Lebesgue integral of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ does not exist.